# Register a route in a DNN module before the existing routes

Tags: signalr, dotnetnuke

I am developing a Signal R application in my DNN website.As i cant amend my global.asax file, i registered a new route. As i am using the same to add controllers for my previous modules, i get an error while negotiating

```
public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration());
    }
}
```

this is my Route Mapper class..  I need to register this route before every other route . Is there a way

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I configured this in DNNCHAT, but here's what I am doing in that module:
https://github.com/ChrisHammond/dnnCHAT/blob/master/Components/RouteMapper.cs

using System.Web.Routing;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
//using DotNetNuke.Web.Services;

```
namespace Christoc.Modules.DnnChat.Components
{
    public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            //RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); //removed for SignalR 2.0.0

        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Another thing you may have to setup is to tell DNN not to rewrite the SignalR path

https://github.com/ChrisHammond/dnnCHAT/blob/master/Data/00.01.00.sqldataprovider

I did that using the SQL in that file

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}HostSettings] WHERE SettingName = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx' )

    insert into {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}hostsettings
    (SettingName
    , SettingValue
    , SettingIsSecure 
    , CreatedByUserId
    , CreatedOnDate
    , LastModifiedByUserId
    , LastModifiedOnDate
    )
    values(
    'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx'
    ,'/DesktopModules/|/Providers|/LinkClick\.aspx|/SignalR'
    , 0
    , -1
    , GETDATE()
    , -1
    , GETDATE()
    )

GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}HostSettings] WHERE SettingName = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx' and SettingValue not like '%/signalr%' )

update {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}hostsettings
    set settingValue = (select settingValue + '|/signalr' from {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}hostsettings where settingname = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx')
where settingname = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx'


GO
```

Comment: I had already tried your sample..But i was not able to generate dynamic hub proxy. So i tried to  Establish a connection (without the generated proxy).. It returns me an error saying http://localhost:8803/DesktopModules/VideoConference/signalr/negotiate?_=1454507861473 not found  @Chris Hammond

Comment: My scripts end up going to /signalr/hubs not underneath the /desktopmodules/MODULENAME I also had to tell DNN not to rewrite that path, see my edit (coming shortly) to the answer for details on that SQL

Comment: thanks for the edit.. But still it is the same . I am unable to generate hub proxy error:GET http://localhost:8803/signalr/hubs @Chris Hammond

Comment: I am already using Routemapper to add a route for another module.. That is executed first when i start the application..I guess that is the problem ..But i don't know how to  change the order and give the hubs first priority.@Chris Hammond